Edges Not Smooth with Displacement Modifier Despite Smooth Shading and Auto Smooth
I have a texture that I use with the Displacement Modifier, applied after a Subdivision Modifier with 5 levels on a grid. There's a zoomed-in version of the lower-left corner of this texture on the right, so you can see that it is pixelated.

I'm having an issue with the Displacement Modifier with Strength set to 0.1. The edges are not smooth even after applying smooth shading and auto smooth. Additionally, the edges are not appearing sharp. Does anyone have any suggestions or help?


